# How to fix Deployment Error in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I am getting following error for a database deploy in Azure devops. Anyone has any idea what could be wrong?

```
2023-08-30 Publishing to database 'Test' on server 'Test-SQL007'.
2023-08-30 Initializing deployment (start)
2023-08-30 Initializing deployment (Failed)
2023-08-30 [Error]*** Could not deploy package.
2023-08-30 Finishing: SQL Package Publish to Test-SQL007
```

I tried deploying and the deploy fails. All the configuration seems to be correct and I compared with other deploys to match the configuration as well.

Appreciate any help or guidance.

Thank you